# Concurrency Azure Web API- SQL Server and Blob

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core

I have a Web API that currently saves data to our SQL Server database. We want to free some space and because one of the columns are large strings, we want to move those out of SQL Server and into Azure Blob storage.

We have the solution ready for new inserts but we also want to move all the already inserted values into Azure blob.

We thought of some background task that would query the table in batches of 10k and upload the values to the Blob Storage, and mark them as "Sent". The issue is that we have more than one instance of the API and we would run into concurrency problems.

Any solution for this issue using EF Core, `DbContext` and transactions / isolation levels so the instances read different batches that can take different amounts of time depending on the size of the strings?

Thank you all for your time.

We tried a few isolation levels and locks on the table but if the second transaction takes lower time than the first it ends with a timeout and error.

Edit:
How it currently works (no code as it is protected, sorry).
Get some records (1k for example, can be modified through setting) using DBContext and EF query where "markedassent" is false.
Process that list sending parallel requests to azure blob, mark the 1k records as sent, save changes in dbcontext.
Works perfectly in testing with 1 instance, but tried it running two instances and they get the same 1k records and process the same.

Comment: why don't you spin up an azure function which time trigger and let it move the data?!

Comment: Unfortunately because of security and deployment requirements they are not willing to do a function nor a azure factory pipeline. They want to solve it within that Web API code.

Comment: i'm not sure what kind of concurrency you would be running into? can't you just copy data into blob and keep reading the original data until the whole load is done

Comment: @siggemannen mainly selecting the same 10k rows and trying to update/send to blob (that will return a already present error). Which using those big strings is quite the load for the application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let each API instance do a specified range.

Comment: @GertArnold how would you do this? Any way with only code? As having differences in settings between instances is not permitted (first thing I suggested was adding a setting that if false it wouldn't run on that instance).

Comment: Yeah, it should be a different setting per instance (something like min/max Id). If that's not permitted, that's merely a question of policy, not a technical restriction and you don't have to comply. As uncle Bob says in *Clean Coder*: say no when you feel demands aren't reasonable. That said, first of all it's a bad decision anyway to let a web application do heavy jobs. Such jobs should always be done by some dedicated process.

Comment: Do you have *any* kind of key which can "split up" the blobs in batches? You should then be able to create a new endpoint which accepts a request that tells it to process blob 1 - 10000 keywise and then advance

Answer (score 0):

After discussing it again and again with the team and higher ups we explained that the best solution was either a new separate process with only 1 instance or using code and a scheduler using Quartz.net which has a property called [DisallowConcurrentExecution] which prevents exactly what we wanted. We ended up going with the Quartz solution as it presented less changes in the azure environment.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).